# Python regex substitution using a dictionary to clean up domain names

Tags: python, regex

For the output, need to replace the brackets contain a digits with periods '.'. Also remove the brackets at the beginning and end of the domain.

Can we use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this and if so how?

**code**

```
import re

log = ["4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 2604 PACKET  0000014DE1921330 UDP Rcv 192.168.1.28   f975   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)",
       "4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 0574 PACKET  0000014DE18C4720 UDP R cv 192.168.2.54    9c63   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)"]

rx_dict = { 'query': re.compile(r'(?P<query>[\S]*)$') }

for item in log:
    for key, r_exp in rx_dict.items():
        print(f"{r_exp.search(item).group(1)}")
```

**output**

```
(7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)
(2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)
```

**preferred output**

```
pagead2.googlesyndication.com
pg.cdn.viber.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pragmatic python usage:**

```
log = ["4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 2604 PACKET  0000014DE1921330 UDP Rcv 192.168.1.28   f975   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (7)pagead2(17)googlesyndication(3)com(0)",
       "4/19/2020 11:59:09 PM 0574 PACKET  0000014DE18C4720 UDP R cv 192.168.2.54    9c63   Q [0001   D   NOERROR] A      (2)pg(3)cdn(5)viber(3)com(0)"]

import re

urls = [re.sub(r'\(\d+\)','.',t.split()[-1]).strip('.') for t in log]

print (urls)
```

Output:

```
['pagead2.googlesyndication.com', 'pg.cdn.viber.com']
```

---

**Dictionary refinement via rules:**

If you want to apply consecutive rules via a dictionary, go `lambda` all the way:

```
import re 

rules = {"r0": lambda x: x.split()[-1],
         "r1": lambda x: re.sub(r'\(\d+\)','.',x),
         "r2": lambda x: x.strip(".")}

result = []
for value in log:  
    result.append(value)
    for r in rules:
        result[-1] = rules[r](result[-1])

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['pagead2.googlesyndication.com', 'pg.cdn.viber.com']
```

Comment: Thanks but how to implement in the code I provided above?

Comment: @pab I doubt you can. You can use the chained solution I detailed under **Dictionary refinement via rules** wich is similar to yours. I can not think of any 1-step regex that solves your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `re.sub`. I assume you have this dictionary so you can extract multiple pieces from the log. You can do something like this for [dispatch](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch01s07.html):

```
ops = {
    "query": lambda e: (
         re.sub(r"\(\d+\(", ".", (
             re.search(r"(?P<query>[\S]*)$", e).group(1),
         )
     ),
     ...
}
```

And then apply the functions to all log entires

```
log_results = {op_name: op(l) for op_name, op in ops.items() for l in log}
```

Comment: typo? `r"\(\d+\)"` ?

Comment: still has a too many `'.'` in the result and you have some ( or ) mismatch.